# PhpStorm & Xdebug pauses execution far far too often

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm 2022.3 and set up a WordPress& MariaDB each in a Docker container, with Xdebug v3.3.0 and PHP 8.2.13 installed.

I set up PhpStorm properly, actually everything is working. However, it's working *too well*. Even when the WordPress container is starting up, execution pauses, the debugger is triggered on `wc-cli.phar` (it's a [`bitname/wordpress`](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress) image, it does a lot when starting up) and I have to *manually* continue the program multiple times before it's loaded.

Whenever I interact with the homepage it triggers on every `*.php` file, including `admin-ajax.php`. Obviously none of those have breakpoints set. My own breakpoint do work, it's just a terrible UX that "random" code points trigger debug breaks.

My `xdebug.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension="/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=/dev/stdout
xdebug.log_level=0
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host="host.docker.internal"
```

I tried with `xdebug.start_with_request=no`, but then breakpoints wouldn't trigger at all, also not mine.

Also, in PhpStorm I didn't need to configure much, I added the path mappings to the WordPress root inside the container. But even only giving a mapping for a deeper subfolder results in the same behavior.

Maybe it's a Xdebug option I'm missing?

Comment: 1) `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` -- that's the reason for the described behaviour -- it tells Xdebug to try and debug **every single request** regardless if "debug me" flag is present (a COOKIE, GET/POST param, ENV var).

Comment: I suggest you check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html and then just use the "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm to listen to incoming debug connections + Xdebug browser extension to set the "debug me" flag in a browser (Xdebug cookie) for your web pages/web requests when needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LazyOne! I have other problems with the docker build right now so I can't try yet, but I'll check back very soon and report.

Comment: There was one more comment (#2)... but I have deleted it. Basically --  `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` either use `default` value or just delete it (since `default` is a default value anyway). Using `no` is not an option... because as the value suggests, Xdebug will NOT be breaking at breakpoints then.